# How do I embed v8 on Windows?

Tags: c++, chromium, v8

How do you compile and embed v8 using Visual Studio on Windows? [The official guide](https://v8.dev/docs/embed) worked on Linux but not on Windows with Visual Studio because I keep getting compile errors while trying to build v8 and the sample project.

Comment: You can use the NuGet package.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions I tried the [`v8-nuget`](https://github.com/pmed/v8-nuget) package with the "hello world" code I posted, and though it compiled, there was a runtime error at `Script::Run()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These instructions have been updated in 2023 for v8 version `11.5.83` on Windows 11.

## Setting up the build environment

1. Follow the ["depot_tools_tutorial"](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html#_setting_up) for Windows. Here is a summary of the instructions.

   1. First, download and extract `depot_tools.zip`.
   2. Then set your PATH variable to the folder.
   3. Create a variable named `DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN` and set it to 0.
   4. Disable [App Execution Alias](https://www.makeuseof.com/app-execution-aliases-guide/) for `python.exe` and `python3.exe`.
   5. Open command prompt (not Powershell) and run `gclient` (from any folder) to download all tools.
   6. Test the setup by running the command `where python`. The depot_tools Python should appear first in the list. Then run `python3 --version` to ensure it outputs as expected.
2. Follow ["Setting up Windows"](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#Setting-up-Windows).

   1. Install Visual Studio 2022 with the following components: Desktop development with C++, and MFC/ATL support.
   2. Install Windows SDK 10.0.22621.0. Download it from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/) and make sure to get the exact version. I first tried downloading the SDK from the Visual Studio Installer but it didn't work as it doesn't come with the required Debugging Tools.
3. [Download the `v8` source code.](https://v8.dev/docs/source-code)

   1. First create a folder called `v8_download`, then open command prompt and `cd` to that folder.
   2. Run `fetch v8` and then `cd v8`.
   3. Checkout the tag `11.5.83` with `git checkout 11.5.83`. I highly recommend using this tag that I tested the instructions on because future versions may change the building steps. After completing all the steps, you can try the latest commit or latest tag.
   4. Download all dependencies by running `gclient sync`.

## Compile v8 as a library

4. Assuming command prompt is still in the `v8_download\v8` folder, run `python3 tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.debug` to generate the configuration file.
5. There was one compilation error, `error C3477`, that I had to fix manually. The diff looks like this. I figured that the `DCHECK_EQ` is just a debug check that I could comment out to fix the error.

```
diff --git a/src/heap/new-spaces.cc b/src/heap/new-spaces.cc
index 43a19fe797..ba9fff6e10 100644
--- a/src/heap/new-spaces.cc
+++ b/src/heap/new-spaces.cc
@@ -1069,11 +1069,11 @@ void PagedSpaceForNewSpace::Verify(Isolate* isolate,

   DCHECK_EQ(current_capacity_, Page::kPageSize * CountTotalPages());

-  DCHECK_EQ(
-      AllocatedSinceLastGC() + limit() - top(),
-      std::accumulate(begin(), end(), 0, [](size_t sum, const Page* page) {
-        return sum + page->AllocatedLabSize();
-      }));
+  // DCHECK_EQ(
+  //     AllocatedSinceLastGC() + limit() - top(),
+  //     std::accumulate(begin(), end(), 0, [](size_t sum, const Page* page) {
+  //       return sum + page->AllocatedLabSize();
+  //     }));
 }
 #endif  // VERIFY_HEAP
```

6. Replace the contents of `v8\out.gn\x64.debug\args.gn` with:

```
is_debug = true
target_cpu = "x64"
v8_enable_backtrace = true
v8_enable_slow_dchecks = true
v8_optimized_debug = false
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false
is_component_build = false
is_clang = false
```

7. Run `ninja -C out.gn/x64.debug v8_monolith`.
8. Run `python3 tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release`.
9. Replace the contents of `v8\out.gn\x64.release\args.gn` with:

```
dcheck_always_on = false
is_debug = false
target_cpu = "x64"
is_component_build = false
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false
is_component_build = false
is_clang = false
```

10. Run `ninja -C out.gn/x64.release v8_monolith`.

## Hello World program

11. Create a new Console App for C++ in Visual Studio.
12. Add the library directories to the project.

    1. Go to your project properties and change the configuration to All Configurations and Platform to All Platforms.
    2. Under VC++ Directories, add the absolute path to `v8\include` to Include Directories. Click Apply after this step and after each of the following steps.

    [image]

    3. Change Configuration to Debug and add the absolute path to `v8\out.gn\x64.debug\obj` to Library Directories.
    4. Repeat step 3 for the Release configuration, with the path to `v8\out.gn\x64.release\obj`.
    5. Change to Debug configuration. Go to C/C++ | Code Generation and change Runtime Library to `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`.
    6. Change to Release configuration. Change Runtime Library to `Multi-threaded (/MT)`.
    7. Change to All Configurations, go to Linker | Input, and add the following files to Additional Dependencies: `v8_monolith.lib;dbghelp.lib;Winmm.lib;`.
    8. Go to C/C++ | Preprocessor and add `V8_ENABLE_SANDBOX;V8_COMPRESS_POINTERS;_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0;` to the Preprocessor Definitions.
13. Replace the `.cpp` file contents with the following code which is `v8\samples\hello-world.cc` but with the include paths corrected.

```cpp
// Copyright 2015 the V8 project authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "libplatform/libplatform.h"
#include "v8-context.h"
#include "v8-initialization.h"
#include "v8-isolate.h"
#include "v8-local-handle.h"
#include "v8-primitive.h"
#include "v8-script.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Initialize V8.
    v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
    v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
    std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
    v8::V8::Initialize();

    // Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.
    v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
    create_params.array_buffer_allocator =
        v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
    v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);
    {
        v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);

        // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
        v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

        // Create a new context.
        v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate);

        // Enter the context for compiling and running the hello world script.
        v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);

        {
            // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
            v8::Local<v8::String> source =
                v8::String::NewFromUtf8Literal(isolate, "'Hello' + ', World!'");

            // Compile the source code.
            v8::Local<v8::Script> script =
                v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

            // Run the script to get the result.
            v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();

            // Convert the result to an UTF8 string and print it.
            v8::String::Utf8Value utf8(isolate, result);
            printf("%s\n", *utf8);
        }

        {
            // Use the JavaScript API to generate a WebAssembly module.
            //
            // |bytes| contains the binary format for the following module:
            //
            //     (func (export "add") (param i32 i32) (result i32)
            //       get_local 0
            //       get_local 1
            //       i32.add)
            //
            const char csource[] = R"(
        let bytes = new Uint8Array([
          0x00, 0x61, 0x73, 0x6d, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x07, 0x01,
          0x60, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x01, 0x7f, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x07,
          0x07, 0x01, 0x03, 0x61, 0x64, 0x64, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x01,
          0x07, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x20, 0x01, 0x6a, 0x0b
        ]);
        let module = new WebAssembly.Module(bytes);
        let instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(module);
        instance.exports.add(3, 4);
      )";

            // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
            v8::Local<v8::String> source =
                v8::String::NewFromUtf8Literal(isolate, csource);

            // Compile the source code.
            v8::Local<v8::Script> script =
                v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

            // Run the script to get the result.
            v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();

            // Convert the result to a uint32 and print it.
            uint32_t number = result->Uint32Value(context).ToChecked();
            printf("3 + 4 = %u\n", number);
        }
    }

    // Dispose the isolate and tear down V8.
    isolate->Dispose();
    v8::V8::Dispose();
    v8::V8::DisposePlatform();
    delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
    return 0;
}
```

14. Compile and run both Debug and Release configurations. They should output:

```
Hello, World!
3 + 4 = 7
```

Comment: This does require your project to disable checked iterators with `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0`. Without it, your project will not compile. You also cannot disable it for one translation unit while others have it enabled. I was not able to patch the v8 code to use checked iterators.

Comment: Can I convert JS to C++ using this method?

Comment: @UahnbuTran No, v8 allows you to run JS inside a c++ program. If you need to run JS in a c++ program, v8 is the best way to do it, aside from rewriting the JS code.

Comment: So will there be any increase in performance?

Comment: @UahnbuTran Compared to running JS in a Chromium browser, they are identical in performance. Chromium uses v8.

Comment: i go link error, if i use msvc. but clang is ok. 
is_clang=true

Comment: my v8 version is 9.9

Comment: This has been very helpful. One thing though... For a release build, should is_official_build = true? I tried doing this but got errors. Seems it was expecting chromium to be present. According to the flag's description, it says that it should be enabled anytime it is intended to be shipped off to an end-user.

Comment: @Nikolas Good question. According to [this page](https://www.chromium.org/developers/gn-build-configuration/#official-chrome-build) that is for building Chrome.

Comment: @MakotoE The quick response is greatly appreciated. The whole point of me doing this was because it appeared that the release build was built with the runtime library set to `Multi-Threaded Static Debug` instead of just `Multi-Threaded Static Release`. I thought that maybe re-building with `is_official_build = true` that it would fix this issue. If you have any insight on the matter, I would appreciate it.

Also, `is_official_build` claims increased optimizations. Would you say that your release config above results in an optimized v8 build?

Thank you.

Comment: @Nikolas Well I'm not sure but I think `is_official_build` is not relevant if you're only building v8. Are you sure you're checking the runtime for the v8 library and not your own app? I assume there is a flag in v8 to control the runtime library. I'll have to try it myself sometime to update the answer.

Comment: Just updated the instructions for the latest v8 on Windows 11! I'll try to update it every year!